# Assign a value to a final one element array variable from an inner class AsyncTask Firebase

Tags: java, android

Here I'm trying to assign a value to a final one element array from an inner class[FirebaseFireStore class], but the value will never change.

```
final boolean[] canPost = {false};
                mFirestore.collection("Users").document(current_user_id).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            if (task.getResult().exists()) {

                                try {
                                    String lastPost = task.getResult().get("last_posted").toString();
                                    boolean isAbleToPost = canHePost(lastPost);
                                    if (!isAbleToPost){
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Can't post");
                                        canPost[0] = false;
                                    }else{
                                        Log.d(TAG, "CAN POST!!");
                                        canPost[0] = true;
                                    }
                                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "User never posted before");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                Log.d("isAllowed to post?", ""+ canPost[0]);
```

Note that here, the `boolean isAbleToPost = canHePost(lastPost);` returns ture
and `Log.d(TAG, "CAN POST!!");` is displayed in the Log, but what is really confusing me is that the last `Log.d("isAllowed to post?", ""+ canPost[0]);` is displayed first - before the first Log !
Log sequence:

```
D/isAllowed to post?: false
D/CAN: CAN POST!!
```

Answer (score 1):

You fetching async data, so of course if you read your code inline your creating a boolean array then your fetching data and add a listener that will trigger **later** on and finally you're logging `Log.d("isAllowed to post?", ""+ canPost[0]);`

If you want your log in your callback then move it up

```
final boolean[] canPost = {false};
                mFirestore.collection("Users").document(current_user_id).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            if (task.getResult().exists()) {

                                try {
                                    String lastPost = task.getResult().get("last_posted").toString();
                                    boolean isAbleToPost = canHePost(lastPost);
                                    if (!isAbleToPost){
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Can't post");
                                        canPost[0] = false;
                                    }else{
                                        Log.d(TAG, "CAN POST!!");
                                        canPost[0] = true;
                                    }
                                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "User never posted before");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Log.d("isAllowed to post?", ""+ canPost[0]);
                     }
                });
```

Comment: thank you. I see it now, but still this doesn't assign the result to the canPost variable. I'm using this variable to check through an if statement `if (canPost[0]) {` later on for another block of code.